# Hyper-V Trunk no internet connectivity

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, hyper-v, vlan

I am attempting to set up a Trunk network adapter for a Hyper-V VM running Linux.

I set it up using the following PowerShell commands:

```
Add-VMNetworkAdapter -VMName Linux -Name "NetworkTrunk"
set-VMNetworkAdapterVlan -VMName Linux -VMNetworkAdapterName "NetworkTrunk" -Trunk -AllowedVlanIdList "31-35" -NativeVLanId 0
```

However when I boot up the VM, it does not receive any network connectivity.  I have my physical unifi switches setup correctly (which I can confirm by setting the network adapter to 1 VLAN via the GUI and it works as intended (i.e. Access mode)).

Why does Trunk Mode not work, but Access Mode does?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that creating the adapter alone was not enough, and I had to connect it to my VSwitch (this step is oddly omitted by most online resources)

```
Connect-VMNetworkAdapter -VMName Linux -Name NetworkTrunk -SwitchName NewSwitch
```